# contentEditable div Multilines issue on FireFox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with `contentEditable="true"

```
<div id="msgInput" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

When the user types in it and presses 'enter' it appends what the user typed to another div

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

But I need it so the user can type multiple lines (with shift+enter) without firing the 'keydown' event on the 'enter' key

Here is how I achieved this: (please note that I added the 'input' event Listener because I need to save what the user types in my state variable)

```
let input = document.getElementById('msgInput');
let output = document.getElementById('output');
let state = '';

input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    state = event.target.textContent;
});

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.target.innerHTML = '';        
        output.innerHTML = state;
        event.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

On Chrome, this is working fine,

for example, If I type "first"

then shift+enter,

then type "second"

and then press enter, it will be appended like this:

```
first
second
```

And that's exactly what I want.

But on firefox, it's appended in one line (merged as one word)

```
firstsecond
```

I need it in firefox to have the same behavior as in chrome

here's a fiddle for this
https://jsfiddle.net/Lrnx24tb/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replace `textContent` for `innerText`:

```
input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    state = event.target.innerText;
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, as far as I know 'textContent' and 'innerText' do the same thing, but maybe some browsers support one and others the other